# How to get a doc from a collection in meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am absolutely unexperienced with mongodb, so I am asking how to retrieve a document from a meteor collection.
I check if there is a doc for the user and update it with an object

```
            if (Saves.find({_id: Meteor.userId()}).fetch()) {

                    console.log("Before " +Saves.find({_id: Meteor.userId()}).fetch())
                    if (Meteor.isServer){
                    Saves.update( {_id: Meteor.userId(), save: save} )
                    }
                    console.log("Success " + Saves.find({_id: Meteor.userId()}).fetch())
```

I want to get that "save" object via `console.log`, but right now they all output nothing or `[object Object]` if I don't use `fetch()` (outputting a cursor object obviously).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, Collection.find() returns a [cursor](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection_cursor), whereas Collection.find().fetch() returns the document.

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do exactly, but maybe something like this (untested):

```
var cursor = Saves.find({ _id : Meteor.userId() /* , save : { $not : true } */ });

cursor.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    Saves.update({ _id : item._id }, { $set : { save : true } });
});
```

You'd wrap the whole thing in a Meteor method to take advantage of latency compensation, and ensure write permission with your Collection.update.